# Haskell: returning strings that are before & after a given string

Tags: string, haskell

Given a type String, should return Strings
eg. given the string "Second" should return -- > "First" , "Third"
That is what is before this string and what is after it. (symmetry relationship in some sense)

Here's what I have tried so far.

```
between :: String ->  (String, String)
between "Second" = (“First”,"Third")
between "Third" = (“Second”,"Fourth")
between "Fourth" = (“Third”, "Fifth")
```

The other one I tried

```
data Positions =  First | Second | Third | Fourth | Fifth |

between :: Positions ->  (String,String)
between Second = (“First”,"Third")
between Third = (“Second”,"Fourth")
between Fourth = (“Third”, "Fifth")
```

Recevied different types of error eg. Undefined variable "?" , Improperly terminated string and Equations give different arities.

How would you fix this in order for it to function well, without any errors?

Comment: The special quotes (`“` and `”`) are a copy&paste problem or you are actually using these quotes in your source file?

Answer (score 1):

You have two syntax errors in this code.  First, you have an extra `|` at the end of your `Positions` type.  I like to write my ADTs a bit differently so that it's easier to see when I've messed up:

```
data Positions
    = First
    | Second
    | Third
    | Fourth
    | Fifth
```

The other error is that you seem to have copy/pasted some non-ascii quote characters into your source around each of the first tuple elements, and that's easily fixed:

```
between :: Positions -> (String, String)
between Second = ("First", "Third")
between Third = ("Second", "Fourth")
between Fourth = ("Third", "Fifth")
```

However, I'll also point out that this could be done a bit easier using a `deriving` clause on your type:

```
data Positions
    = First
    | Second
    | Third
    | Fourth
    | Fifth
    deriving (Eq, Enum, Bounded)

between :: Positions -> Maybe (Positions, Positions)
between p =
    if p == minBound || p == maxBound
        then Nothing
        else Just (pred p, succ p)
```

This uses `Maybe` to make the function safer as well, it can't crash your program if you call `between First`.  If you really want the strings instead, you can `derive (Eq, Enum, Bounded, Show)` instead and use `Just (show $ pred p, show $ succ p)`

Answer (score 0):

Respecting the signature you've proposed at the start of your question (String -> (String, String)) it could look something like this:

```
between :: String -> (String, String)
between x = case x of
  "Second" -> ("First","Third")
  "Third"  -> ("Second","Fourth")
  "Fourth" -> ("Third","Fifth")
```